# find first element followed n elements of same

Tags: netlogo

How can I find the first zero's index which is followed by 5 zeros in a list? In case no such zero exists return -1. 
Netlogo only returns the first element found in a  list with `position` which makes it difficult/cumbersome.

Comment: So you want the start of the first sequence of 6 zeroes in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question you say you want `-1` back if it isn't found, but that doesn't match the behavior of NetLogo's own `position` primitive, which returns `false` if the item isn't found. I'd suggest sticking with the usual NetLogo convention for this.

Recursive solution:

```
to-report position-of-six-zeros [xs]
  if length xs < 6
    [ report false ]
  if sublist xs 0 6 = [0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [ report 0 ]
  let recurse position-of-six-zeros butfirst xs
  if not is-number? recurse
    [ report recurse ]
  report 1 + recurse
end
```

Sample runs:

```
observer> show position-of-six-zeros [0 0 0 0 0]
observer: false
observer> show position-of-six-zeros [0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
observer: 0
observer> show position-of-six-zeros [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6]
observer: 3
observer> show position-of-six-zeros [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6]
observer: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution. Maybe there are smarter ways to achieve the same, but at least this approach should work.
You define a list, the length of the sequence you want to look at and the number, which the sequence should have. Then you call the reporter function (check-sequence) with that information.
The reporter function then uses a while loop. It takes the next `length-of-sequence` elements and filters this sublist by the specified `number-of-interest`. If the length of this filtered list is the same as the specified `length-of-sequence` the function will store the actual position on the whole list (`i`). If not, the first element of the list will be dropped and the loop runs again. If there are not enough elements left in the list, the loop will stop and set the reporter to -1. Otherwise it will report the starting position of the sequence.

```
to go

   let my-list (list 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 8 9 8)
   let length-of-sequence 4
   let number-of-interest 0

   print check-sequence my-list length-of-sequence number-of-interest

end   

to-report check-sequence [a-list sequence number]

  let i 0
  let stopper 0
  let reporter 0

  while [stopper = 0]
  [
    let filtered_sublist filter [? = number] (sublist a-list 0 sequence)    
    if (length filtered_sublist = sequence)
    [ 
      set reporter i
      set stopper 1
    ] 

    set a-list but-first a-list
    set i (i + 1)

    if (length a-list < sequence)
    [
      set stopper 2
    ]
  ]

  ifelse (stopper = 2)
  [ report -1 ]
  [ report reporter ]

end
```